# Gsuite Migration resulting in changing every documents URL, write a script to update every url in every document (1million+)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My organization is upgrading our Gsuite resulting in every docID being changed.  Throughout our million+ documents there are many that link to other documents, sometimes for user convenience, sometime for scripts to link them.  We want to update all the urls with a script.

We will receive a spreadsheet that has column A: List of old IDs Column B: List of new ids Column C: Owner. Currently our solution is to open every doc, search it for each old ID on the list, and replace with the corresponding new one.  It works, but the run time is looking at 5years. Anyone have a better solution?

Here is our code for spreadsheets, its similar for Documents and Slides

```
var oldurls = mSheet.getRange("A2:A"+filesize).getValues();
var newurls = mSheet.getRange("B2:B"+filesize).getValues();

for(var row in newurls) {
gSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById(newurls[row]); 

for(var i = 0; i < oldurls.length; i++)   
  {
 gSheet.createTextFinder(oldurls[i]).matchEntireCell(false).matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith(newurls[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the Sheets API in order to update the values from the Spreadsheet.

To get yourself started, I suggest you use the **Sheets API Quickstart** [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) and later adapt it to fit your needs accordingly.

When using the Sheets API, it's also important to take into account the current limitations regarding the quota. According to the Sheets API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits):

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.

You can also get this done in Apps Script using the **Sheets** advanced service, however, this will end up falling under Apps Script's [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) as well.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Basic Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading);
- [Sheets API Basic Writing](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing);
- [Sheets API Quota](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits);
- [Apps Script Quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).